# List style for additional dots

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a CSS property or list style that would be able to display a list of increasing size. Something like

```html
Buy now to get a discount!

<ol style="list-style: none">
  <li>* Only available for the first 12 months</li>
  <li>** Only available for new customers signing up for a paid plan</li>
</ol>
```

In my particular case there's an arbitrary number of `<li>` tags though, so it'd be best if the CSS styling could handle increasing the number of asterisks per line without me needing to hard code or calculate it myself.

Comment: A list isn’t the right structure for footnotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to nest the lists. Just use a symbolic counter style:

```css
@counter-style asterisks {
  system: symbolic;
  symbols: "*";
  suffix: " ";
}

ol { 
  list-style: asterisks inside;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Only available for the first 12 months</li>
  <li>Only available for new customers signing up for a paid plan</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This is cool! Didn't know this was possible in vanilla CSS!

Answer (score 2):

This is done automatically, you just need to nest `<ol>` in a deeper level:

```css
ol {
  list-style: '*';
  padding-inline-start: .5em;
}
```

```html
Buy now to get a discount!

<ol>
  <li>Only available for the first 12 months</li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>Only available for new customers signing up for a paid plan</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```